# Horizontal Recyclerview overlays in next View Pager fragment on scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a View pager containing 3 fragments (with FragmentPagerAdapter), one of the fragments has a horizontal Recyclerview as a part of it. when I scroll the view pager from one fragment(containing horizontal recyclerview) to another, remaining part of the last visible recyclerview item overlays next fragment on scroll.

**MainAcitivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    fragment0 = new Fragment0();
    fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    fragment2 = new Fragment2();

    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(fragment0, "A");
    adapter.addFragment(fragment1, "B");
    adapter.addFragment(fragment2, "C");
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

**PagerAdapter**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public PagerAdapter (FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
```

}

and the recycler view is a simple horizontal recyclerview containing a custom view

please do help me.....

Answer (score 0):

Change the recyclerview's(i mean the contents of your recyclerview) width

Comment: I have set recyclerview single  item width as wrap content and recyclerview width as match parent, do I need to change it??